# What to do in PhpStorm because of bitbucket ssh key rotation?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, phpstorm

[https://bitbucket.org/blog/ssh-host-key-changes#:~:text=To%20verify%20which%20host%20key,key%2Dchanges%20for%20more%20details](https://bitbucket.org/blog/ssh-host-key-changes#:%7E:text=To%20verify%20which%20host%20key,key%2Dchanges%20for%20more%20details).

> We highly recommend that you immediately switch to using the newer
> ECDSA or Ed25519 host keys for each of your SSH clients that connect
> to bitbucket.org, including other applications such as IDEs and CI/CD
> build systems.

If using PhpStorm for git operations like pushes, do I need to do something in PhpStorm if I have done the actions in command line (Ubuntu terminal) which are described in that link above?

I thought maybe PhpStorm is reusing the same SSH command at least in Linux. But today I noticed that this page writes that we need switch host keys for IDEs also.

If so, how? Run those commands in PhpStorm terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely no.

IDE relies on your default terminal config and inherits variables from there and sends commands directly to terminal (as when you push manually from terminal, too)

Did you test?

Comment: Test what? I executed in ubuntu terminal `ssh git@bitbucket.org host_key_info` . If you are sure it relies on terminal config, then why most likely and not 100 % ?